# Variance calculation after k-modes in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, variance

How to find of all clusters have different variances in a parameter after k-modes have been applied? We applies k-modes clustering and then plotted the clusters using CLUSPLOT and are clusters came to be too much overlapping. To test that we wanted to apply t-test, for which we need to find variances of variables in all clusters. But because we have categorical data, how should we calculate the variance?

[image: My attempt to calculate variance and t-test]

Comment: A reproducible example along with data will be of great help to help you in return!

Comment: Just added an image to my earlier post

Comment: can you please `dput` your data

Comment: You want to see my data?

Answer (score 0):

Variance, and clusplot is also based on this concept, mostly makes sense for continuous variables. It's rooted in least squares estimation, so you need something to compute squares and square roots.

Just trying to apply these things to categorical or binary variables usually fails to give good results. So you will have to come up with an approach that makes sense for your domain/application. The "turnkey" solution of variance won't do.

Comment: I am modeling user preferences of using smart devices. i have seen k-modes being applies to privacy preferences in the past. where they calculated variance of parameters, and then as it was different did welch t-test.